# "Antier" para expresar el día anterior a ayer

Tags: definiciones, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos

Hace unos días mientras me encontraba cambiando de canal en la televisión por cable, escuche una conversación de una película estadounidense doblada al español. Dos personas estaban en un bar conversando. La parte de interés de la conversación es la siguiente:

> Mujer: ¿Cuándo llegaste?
>
> Hombre: Antier

Tengo entendido que para referirse al día antes de ayer se usa normalmente "anteayer" o "antes de ayer". Quisiera saber si "antier" es algún tipo de jerga local o si es aceptada para referirse al día antes de ayer.

En Perú, no he escuchado a ninguna persona utilizar este término.

Comment: En Cuba si he oido utilizar antier

Comment: En cuba se usa mucho un chiste para referirse cuando la comida está vieja. `Esa comida es francesa, es de antiegr`

Comment: Pues no tenía ni idea que en México no conocieran la palabra "anteayer" y sólo utilizasen "antier"... Ésta última la he escuchado alguna vez pero coloquialmente y en personas con poca instrucción ( digo: en España y en Sudamérica).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En el diccionario de la Real Academia de la Lengua Española, señala a [*antier*](http://dle.rae.es/antier) como la forma coloquial de anteayer, es decir es exactamente lo mismo, pero en un contexto muchísimo más informal. Es decir, sí estás en lo cierto es jerga, pero del Español como idioma.

---

En [este link](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=t0758ziWh2x5OaUnh50), que me han pasado en [un comentario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/antier-para-expresar-el-d%c3%ada-anterior-a-ayer#comment4864_2965), me comentan que en la revisión de la palabra, ya no es coloquial.

Comment: De hecho el articulo enmendado de la liga que citaste : http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=t0758ziWh2x5OaUnh50 ya no dice que es coloquial.

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio ¡Muchas gracias! Lo incluyo en la respuesta.

Answer (score 12):

"antier" es de uso común aquí en México para referirse al día antes de ayer. De hecho jamás he escuchado a alguien decir "anteayer" aquí. El uso de "antier" en México lo confirma la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=anteayer) según la siguiente cita.

> anteayer. ‘En el día anterior a ayer’. También puede usarse la
>   locución antes de ayer; pero la grafía anteayer es la preferida en el
>   uso por su brevedad. La variante antier, más cercana al étimo latino
>   (lat. ante heri), **es de uso corriente en algunos países de América,
>   sobre todo en México y el área centroamericana,** aunque en España no
>   pertenece a la norma culta y solo se emplea en el habla rural o
>   popular: «La dependiente me preguntó qué me había parecido el mantón
>   de Manila que antier me había comprado el general» (Mastretta Vida
>   [Méx. 1990]). Deben evitarse las formas antiayer y antiyer, ajenas a
>   la norma culta en todo el ámbito hispánico.

Comment: Efectivamente, en Centroamérica es común y raras veces se utiliza la forma "anteayer".

Comment: Increíblemente yo ni si quiera sabia que existía "anteayer". Tengo la impresión de que "Antier" es la única forma en México.

Comment: En Colombia **antier** es la norma. Casi nadie dice "anteayer".

Answer (score -2):

Así es. Lo usan las personas de escasa cultura. Muchas personas de las capitales lo usan y no por eso significa que es correcto. Es parecido al decir "echa pa' allá" en vez de "echa para allá". Aunque lo correcto es "hazte a un lado".

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Que sea coloquial no quiere decir que sea incorrecto. Según [el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=antier): "La variante _antier_, más cercana al étimo latino (lat. _ante heri_), es de uso corriente en algunos países de América, sobre todo en México y el área centroamericana, aunque en España no pertenece a la norma culta y solo se emplea en el habla rural o popular." No indica en ningún momento que sea incorrecta, como son los casos de _antiayer_ y _antiyer_.

Comment: Depende de donde vivas. En México lo usa tanto alguien con un doctorado como un carpintero.

Answer (score -4):

"Antier" es una forma popular -substándar- de "anteayer". Mis abuelos -de pueblo- lo decían, y en el pueblo de Castilla de donde eran, hay gente mayor que todavía lo dice. Usarlo denota poca escolarización.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con el comentario de cierre de tu respuesta, quizás eso sea cierto en España, pero no en todo el mundo de habla hispana.

Comment: "Usarlo denota poca escolarización." Esto casi que me ofende...

Comment: puedes decirle eso a 11 millones de cubanos que dicen `antier`

Comment: y 120 millones de mexicanos :p

Comment: y 48 millones de Colombianos :-)  {esto ya es _bullying_  jajaja}

Comment: Los "puristas", igual que los pobres, son siempre entre nosotros.