# ¿Se utilizan "trasantier" y "trasanteayer" en el habla común?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, adverbios

Leyendo la pregunta [**“Antier” para expresar el día anterior a ayer**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/antier-para-expresar-el-d%C3%ADa-anterior-a-ayer), las respuestas y comentarios, he visto que *antier* es totalmente desconocida en algunas regiones y es la palabra habitual en otras - y que lo recíproco ocurre con *anteayer* y *antes de ayer*.

Esto me hace plantearme si ocurre algo similar con [**trasantier**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aOyFVid)

> 1. adv. p. us. trasanteayer.

y [**trasanteayer**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aOxwmzy)

> 1. adv. p. us. En el día que precedió inmediatamente al de anteayer.

¿Se utilizan en el habla común? ¿Hay diferencias regionales?

Answer (score 2):

Fíjate que a diferencia de lo que pasaba con *[antier](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2rYjC70)*, que el propio diccionario recoge que es una palabra "usada más en América", en el caso de *trasantier* y *trasanteayer* ya directamente te dice que son adverbios "poco usados".

Personalmente, es la primera vez que los oigo, aunque sí había visto antes ese prefijo *[tras-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aI82hct)* en construcciones similares, como *[trasabuelo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aOpkvqA)* o *[trastatarabuelo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Nomenclatura_de_parentesco_en_espa%C3%B1ol#Trastatarabuelos)*. Estas palabras son en general poco usadas (esta última ni siquiera está en el DLE), tal vez por requerir un pequeño esfuerzo mental para descomponer la palabra y entenderla completamente.

Buscando ejemplos, en el CORDE aparecen cuatro casos (sumando ambas formas *trasantier* y *trasanteayer*): tres recientes (de textos de Cuba, Colombia y Venezuela) y uno más antiguo de nuestro amigo Korreas, mencionando una lista de adverbios de tiempo:

> *Oi, aier, anteaier, ó antier, trasantier, manaña, pasado mañana ó esotro dia, tarde, tenprano, aora ó agora, antes, despues [...].*
>
> Gonzalo Correas, "Arte de la lengua española castellana", 1625 (España).

Comment: ¿Nuestro amigo Korreas?

Comment: @aparente001 Gonzalo de Correas, intentó revolucionar la ortografía española allá por el siglo XVII sin mucho éxito, y casi diría que se ha convertido en una especie de broma recurrente del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

En Colombia yo no he escuchado a la primera persona utilizar "trasantier" ni "trasanteayer" en ninguna de las regiones en las que he estado, yo personalmente no sabía ni siquiera que existían estas palabras. La expresión que más he escuchado sinónima a estas palabras es:

> ante-anteayer

de resto se utilizan referencias numericas:

> Hace 2 días estuve en la casa de un amigo.

y referencias de días

> El martes estuve en la casa de un amigo.

Antier sí se utiliza comúnmente al igual que anteayer, antes de ayer es menos común al menos en bogotá pero también se utiliza.